# web push notification body not displaying

Tags: php, push-notification

i am using php web push to send notification

here is php code

```
$notifContent888 = array(
       'title' => 'test tiltle',
       'body' => 'This is the body content',
       'icon' => 'https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/08/05/1057a3fae73b91b.jpg',
);


$pay_load9988=json_encode($notifContent888);

$subscription_new = Subscription::create([
                'endpoint' => $endpoint,
                'publicKey' => $publicKey_99,
                'authToken' => $authToken,
                'contentEncoding' => $contentEncoding,
]);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);

$webPush->sendNotification($subscription_new, $pay_load9988, true);
```

here is service worker js part

```
if (event.data) {
    var payload = event.data.json();
    var title = payload.title;
    var body  = payload.body;
    var icon  = payload.icon;
    console.log(payload); 
    event.waitUntil(sendNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        data: {} 
}
```

I can see that in console.log all data came nicely but i get notification only with default title and body and icons are not displayed. i can see body and icons in console and if i replace title with body i can see body content but i dont know what is happening only one part i am able to send notification through payload only first part whatever i mention just after sendNotification(title

here only title will come

any help in finding out mistake will be great. is this encryption issue of payload??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `sendNotification` you don't need to encrypt the data since `sendNotification` does it already for you. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push

So you should change your code like this:

```
$notifContent888 = array(
       'title' => 'test tiltle',
       'body' => 'This is the body content',
       'icon' => 'https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/08/05/1057a3fae73b91b.jpg',
);

$subscription_new = Subscription::create([
                'endpoint' => $endpoint,
                'publicKey' => $publicKey_99,
                'authToken' => $authToken,
                'contentEncoding' => $contentEncoding,
]);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth);

$webPush->sendNotification($subscription_new, $notifContent888, true);
```